# Make a listview with a onClicklistener that copies the content to clipboard

Tags: dart, flutter

So I have been trying to port my Android and iOS application to Flutter/Dart so I do not have to code everything twice.

I need to display a ListView(that fetches the contents from an array, and then an onClickListener that copies the clicked items content to clipboard.
All fine and good, I have tried two different methods for displaying the ListView from an array and that works fine but I have not gotten the onClickListener to work at all.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Code like this should work:

```
class ClipBoardCopier extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<String> data = ['Hello', 'Flutter'];
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: data.length,
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return ListTile(
          title: Text('ListTile #$index'),
          onTap: (){
            Clipboard.setData(ClipboardData(text: data[index]));
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

But if Your ListView Item Widget doesn't have Event Listener (onTap, onClick ..) you can wrap it with GestureDetector And you are good to go.

Comment: Clipboard.setData(ClipboardData(text: data[index])); throws out an error. Seems like 'Clipboard' is not a existent function in the newest Dart build

Comment: @JúlíusGuðni Don't forget to add `import 'package:flutter/services.dart';`